# How to re-install Windows 10 education after upgrade to Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10

I got a laptop from the government that had a pre-installed Windows 10 education volume license, I decided to upgrade it to Windows 11 but it wasn’t activating. Since it had been more than 10 days I was unable to go back to Windows 10 education.

I decided to download the ISO file for Windows 10 which has a bunch of options for installing different kinds of Windows into a USB flash drive and enter the product key but it says it isn't suitable for this version thus I’m even more confused. Is it because it’s a volume license that I can’t install again?

I have the product key and product ID of Windows 10 education (I don’t know if it will be of any help), how do I re-install the Windows 10 education volume license again.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: How did you obtain the product key? Do you happen to have the channel name, product name, etc.? (Was it a KMS key or a MAK key? Was it "Education" or "Pro Education"?) Did you purchase the laptop outright or is it leased to you?

Comment: You can’t activate a KMS license without a KMS. There is a routine KMS check. You need to purchase your own license. There is no way to activate Education without a KMS.

Comment: BTW, you'll only get, about 1.5 years on Windows 10 before EOL. If you can't or don't want to buy a Windows 11 license, or the PC does not have compatible hardware, consider another OS. Some, such as Linux, can be tested from USB without installing.